# Join Pandas DataFrames on Fuzzy/Approximate Matches for Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames that look like this. Trying to join the two data sets on 'Name','Longitude', and 'Latitude' but using a fuzzy/approximate match. Is there a way to join these together using a combination of the 'Name' strings being, for example, at least an 80% match and the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' columns being the nearest value or within like 0.001 of each other? I tried using pd.merge_asof but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Thank you for the help!

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['Game Time Bar',42.3734,-71.1204,4.5],['Sports Grill',42.3739,-71.1214,4.6],['Sports Grill 2',42.3839,-71.1315,4.3]]
data2 = [['Game Time Sports Bar',42.3738,-71.1207,'$$'],['Sports Bar & Grill',42.3741,-71.1216,'$'],['Sports Grill',42.3841,-71.1316,'$$']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Latitude','Longitude','Rating'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 'Latitude','Longitude','Price'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge_asof` won't work here since it can only merge on a single numeric column, such as datetimelike, integer, or float (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)).

Here you can compute the (euclidean) distance between the coordinates of df1 and df2 and pickup the best match:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

data1 = [['Game Time Bar',42.3734,-71.1204,4.5],['Sports Grill',42.3739,-71.1214,4.6],['Sports Grill 2',42.3839,-71.1315,4.3]]
data2 = [['Game Time Sports Bar',42.3738,-71.1207,'$$'],['Sports Bar & Grill',42.3741,-71.1216,'$'],['Sports Grill',42.3841,-71.1316,'$$']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 'Latitude','Longitude','Rating'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 'Latitude','Longitude','Price'])

# Replacing 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' columns with a 'Coord' Tuple
df1['Coord'] = df1[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].apply(lambda x: (x['Latitude'], x['Longitude']), axis=1)
df1.drop(columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], inplace=True)
df2['Coord'] = df2[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].apply(lambda x: (x['Latitude'], x['Longitude']), axis=1)
df2.drop(columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], inplace=True)

# Creating a distance matrix between df1['Coord'] and df2['Coord']
distances_df1_df2 = cdist(df1['Coord'].to_list(), df2['Coord'].to_list())

# Creating df1['Price'] column from df2 and the distance matrix
for i in df1.index:
    # you can replace the following lines with a loop over distances_df1_df2[i]
    # and reject names that are too far from each other
    min_dist = np.amin(distances_df1_df2[i])
    if min_dist > 0.001:
        continue
    closest_match = np.argmin(distances_df1_df2[i])
    # df1.loc[i, 'df2_Name'] = df2.loc[closest_match, 'Name']   # keep track of the merged row
    df1.loc[i, 'Price'] = df2.loc[closest_match, 'Price']
    
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
             Name  Rating                Coord Price
0   Game Time Bar     4.5  (42.3734, -71.1204)    $$
1    Sports Grill     4.6  (42.3739, -71.1214)     $
2  Sports Grill 2     4.3  (42.3839, -71.1315)    $$
```

Edit: your requirement on 'Name' ("at least an 80% match") isn't really appropriate. Take a look at [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzywuzzy-how-to-measure-string-distance-on-python-4e8852d7c18f) to get a sense of how string distances can be measured.

Comment: Thank you!! This is super helpful. I was trying to add the "Name" component as a control since the coordinates may vary between the two dataframes and end up joining two different businesses that are right next to each other for example.

Comment: for the name matching `rapidfuzz` can be used which provides the same `cdist` api as scipy for string matching: https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html#cdist: `rapidfuzz.process.cdist(df1['Name'], df2['Name'], score_cutoff=80, workers=-1)`

Comment: @maxbachmann wow that's great and amazingly appropriate!